# How to fill the texture within a reactangle and fill (0.0,0.0,0.0) outside reactangle in a destination texture.?

Tags: image-processing, opengl, opengl-es

There are 2 textures.

Destination texture - 720*1080
source texture - 300*300

Help required:

We need to put source texture onto destination texure at a given location (x center, y center, height and width) and fill the remaining destination texture with 0,0.

Challenge we are facing is that source texture is getting enlarged to the size of destination texture.

[image]

I tried this to do in it in shader coder as follows.

```
// Texture Coordinates 
static const GLfloat square_vertices[] = {
      -1.0f, -1.0f,  // bottom left
      1.0f,  -1.0f,  // bottom right
      -1.0f, 1.0f,   // top left
      1.0f,  1.0f,   // top right
  };
  static const GLfloat texture_vertices[] = {
      0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
      1.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
      0.0f, 1.0f,  // top left
      1.0f, 1.0f,  // top right
  };


// program
  glUseProgram(upsample_program_);

  // vertex storage
  GLuint vbo[2];
  glGenBuffers(2, vbo);
  GLuint vao;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
  glBindVertexArray(vao);
// vbo 0
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), square_vertices,
               GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
  glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, nullptr);

  // vbo 1
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), texture_vertices,
               GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTURE_POSITION);
  glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_TEXTURE_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, nullptr);

  // draw
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

  // cleanup
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_TEXTURE_POSITION);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
  glBindVertexArray(0);
  glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
  glDeleteBuffers(2, vbo);


// Frame drawing
output_width=720;
output_height=1080;
// Upsample small mask into output.
GlTexture output_texture = CreateDestinationTexture(
      output_width, output_height,GpuBufferFormat::kBGRA32);
  {
    gpu_helper_.BindFramebuffer(output_texture);  // GL_TEXTURE0
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    //small_mask_texture is the texture need to render inside the react.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, small_mask_texture.id());
    GlRender();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    
    glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(upsample_program_, "rcenters"),normx_center,normy_center);
    glUniform2f(glGetUniformLocation(upsample_program_, "rhw"),normalized_width,normalized_height);
    glFlush();
  }
```

Here is my shader code;

```
  #if __VERSION__ < 130
    #define in varying
  #endif  // __VERSION__ < 130

  #ifdef GL_ES
    #define fragColor gl_FragColor
    precision highp float;
  #else
    #define lowp
    #define mediump
    #define highp
    #define texture2D texture
    out vec4 fragColor;
  #endif  // defined(GL_ES)

  in vec2 sample_coordinate;
  uniform sampler2D input_data;
  uniform vec2 rcenters;
  uniform vec2 rhw;

  void main() {
    vec4 pix = texture2D(input_data, sample_coordinate);
    float xcenter = rcenters.s;
    float ycenter = rcenters.t;
    float rwidth = rhw.s;
    float rheight = rhw.t;
    if(rwidth != 0.0 && rheight != 0.0){
         float cox =  sample_coordinate.s;
         float coy =  sample_coordinate.t;
         float xmin = xcenter-(rwidth/2.0);
         float ymin = ycenter-(rheight/2.0);
         float xmax = xcenter+(rwidth/2.0);
         float ymax = ycenter+(rheight/2.0);
         if((xmin<cox && xmax>cox) && (ymin<coy && ymax>coy)){
            fragColor = pix;
         }
         else{
             fragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
         }
    }
    else{
        fragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    }

    
  }
```

With this solution I am getting source texture enlarge equal to destination texture. I understand that I need to do something with texture coordinates in vertex but don't know what.

Comment: Is this app going to get more sophisticated? Typically, you would pass a matrix to the vertex shader to multiply by the vertex positions to project them to the correct position on the frame buffer. If you're never going to do much beyond this, you could cheat and manually position them.